# Быстрый перенос директорий

Tags: c#, windows, файлы, файловая-система, totalcommander

Как можно достичь быстрого переноса директорий из одного места на диске в другое место на этом же диске?

Пример:

Исходные директории

```
D:\1\Директория\[Уникальное название директории]\Файлы
D:\2\Директория\[Уникальное название директории]\Файлы
D:\3\Директория\[Уникальное название директории]\Файлы
```

В итоге должно быть так:

```
D:\Директория\[Уникальное название директории]\Файлы
```

Т.е просто пропадает 1 уровень вложенности.

Так вот, когда переносится 1-ая директория в корень, то перенос происходит моментально Total Commannder'ом вне зависимости от размеров и файлов, а последующие начинают переносится уже долго.

Можно ли добиться моментального переноса остальных директорий или это ограничений файловой системы?

Я подозреваю, что при первом переносе меняется всего лишь корневой уровень в MFT => осуществляется пакетный перенос, а при последующих переносах уже идет перенос по файлам, так как идут лишние проверки на существование, ОДНАКО пути уникальные и пересечения не возможно.

Подозреваю, что параллелизм переноса создаст здоровенную очередь и убьет диск.

Comment: Ну понятно, первый перенос — это по сути переименование каталога, это быстро. А вот остальные — это уже честный перенос.

Comment: @VladD, хм... А почему в остальных случаях такого же переименования быть не может, если папка в которой лежат файлы не пересекается с тем, что уже перенесли? А если при последующих переносах все не в корень переносить каталог Директория, а в D:\Директория\, при этом явно выбрав уникальные названия папок? Попробую поэкспериментировать.

Comment: Потому что вам реально придётся изменять содержимое целевого каталога. А это медленнее. Сам файл, по идее, переноситься не должен, если это на том же диске, просто переносятся указатели из каталога. Но это для больших файлов! А маленький файл вполне может храниться внутри directory entry для оптимизации, так что для них нужно физическое копирование.